# How to eliminate space for a null node in a tree

Tags: diagrams, forest, trees

Using the forest package, I using the following code

```
\begin{forest}
for tree={
            grow'=east,
            anchor=west,
            node options={font=\itshape, align=center, },
            forked edges,
            l sep=4mm,
            s sep=2mm,
            fork sep = 2mm, 
            where level=0{anchor=center,draw=none}{},
            where level=1{s sep=1mm,draw=none}{},
          where level=2{s sep=1mm,draw=none}{},
           where level=3{s sep=1mm,draw=none}{},
            where level=4{s sep=1mm,draw=none}{},
              where level=5{s sep=1mm,draw=none}{},
              where level=6{s sep=1mm,draw=none}{},
              where level=7{s sep=1mm,draw=none}{},
        },
[Papilionoidea,
    [Papilionidae]
    [
      [
        [Hedylidae]
        [Hesperiidae]
      ] % b
      [
        [
          [Pieridae]
          [
            [
              [Riodinidae]
              [Lycaenidae]
            ] % f
            [
              [
                [Nymphalidae]
              ] % h
            ] % g
          ] % e
        ] % d
      ] % c
    ] % a
  ] % Papilionoidea
\end{forest}
```

However, this produces space for the null nodes. How do I get rid of the space so that the lines are joined up?

Comment: Please provide a complete example, which begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: inner/outer sep=0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "normal" node will have some width and height even if it is empty. This is true both in Forest and in TikZ, which Forest is built upon. You can see this if you compile this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The simplest (and also the most proper) way to create a node with zero width and height, is to set it's shape to `coordinate`, and this is what I did below.

Now, as we want all nodes without content to be coordinates, we put `coordinate` within a Forest's `where` loop. And we put this loop into a Forest's temporal `delay`, because if we didn't, the loop would be executed before the nodes received any content, so it would change all nodes to coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=east,
    anchor=west,
    font=\itshape,
    forked edge,
    fork sep = 2mm, 
    l sep=4mm,
    s sep=1mm,
  },
  s sep=2mm,
  % delay={
  %   where content={}{coordinate}{},
  % },
  [Papilionoidea,
    [Papilionidae]
    [
      [
        [Hedylidae]
        [Hesperiidae]
      ] % b
      [
        [
          [Pieridae]
          [
            [
              [Riodinidae]
              [Lycaenidae]
            ] % f
            [
              [
                [Nymphalidae]
              ] % h
            ] % g
          ] % e
        ] % d
      ] % c
    ] % a
  ] % Papilionoidea
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also took the liberty to fix several other issue with the code.

1. Never put a `where` inside `for tree` (unless you really know what you're doing). This creates a double loop. It is therefore very inefficient and can sometimes even lead to subtle problems.
2. In fact, all the `where level`s did almost nothing, so I removed them. The only effect they had was that the root was the only node with `s sep=2mm`. See how that is achieved below: `s sep=1mm` within `for tree`, and `s sep=2mm` outside the tree.
3. `forked edges` is a `for tree` loop over `forked edge` (note the absence of the final `s`). So within `for tree`, you should use the latter (as point 1 above).
4. `align=center` sets the internal alignment of multiline nodes, so it is not needed here.

Comment: Thank you for answer

Comment: If it solved your problem, click accept -- that's how you say thanks around here ;-)